# Django filter based on SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a similar type of code provided below.

serializer.py

```
class FooSerailizer(BaseModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    def get_value(self,obj):
        # some statement of code
        # return statement

    class meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

filters.py

```
class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

The API request is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?value=some_value`.

The response I am getting when I am calling the above API:

```
{
    "value": [
        "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

How to get the JSON response correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Django cannot filter based on serializer, you will need to create a custom filter field in your filterset. Check out https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html.